# How to send a notification from the GSOAP service

Tags: c++, xml, server, client-server, onvif

There is a simple gsoap server in C++ based on onvif. I need to implement notifications about events. How can I send notifications via soap? The server has released the devicemgmt.wsdl and event.wsdl services and implemented event subscription. However, I don't understand how to send information about the event to the client when there is no standard request-response in this case.

[schematic from onvif documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYMsV.png)

There are very few examples of onvif based server implementation, so it is very difficult for me to understand this issue myself. I could not find an answer in the official documentation either. I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Don't concern yourself that is is "onvif".  You need to send SOAP HTTP requests.  Do a search for "c++ soap"

Comment: If you implement it over HTTP then the response is simple, you can't. But if you use full duplex TCP or Web Socket, then is as simple as sending any kind of data via network. After the TCP connection is established there is no difference between server and client as long as the connection is kept open.